# Comparacion de 90 numeros en un array de 15

Tags: array, c

Debo realizar un trabajo de clases en el cual tengo que generar 90 números sin repetir en una variable llamada `bolas`. Esos números debo compararlos en una variable llamada `cartones` que tiene 3 filas y 5 columnas=

```
carton[3][5];
```

Ya hice la generación de números aleatorios sin repetirse en las bolas, y también hice la generación de números aleatorios en el cartón. Pero lo que no se me ocurre es como realizar el encontrar las bolas ya generadas en los números del cartón. Es decir, un ejemplo:

```
bolas[5] = {1, 5, 4, 9, 5};

carton [3][5] = {1, 0, 4, 43, 21,
                 41, 53, 46, 86, 66,
                  84, 41, 7, 8, 9}
```

Yo lo que tendría que hacer es esos 5 números generados en las bolas (Es un ejemplo, en realidad se generan 90), marcarlos en el cartón utilizando una x.

Se me ocurrió hacer el típico `if` que compare el numero salido en la bola con la matriz, y eso que me lo cambie por una `x`. Pero tendría que comparar un solo numero de la bola por todo el cartón, y que luego avance, y la verdad no se me ocurre como realizarlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que intentes hacer algo y luego preguntes por una duda concreta porque aquí no suelen ser muy bien recibidas las preguntas de "Tengo que hacer esto para clase" si no has probado primero algo. Te lo digo para evitarte votos negativos o que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Nono, suelo utilizar este foro como ultimo recurso, estoy probando distintos for anidados, bucles, de todo tipo, pero nada bien hecho y ningun resultado. No quiero pasar algo mal hecho o sin sentido

Comment: Nono, suelo utilizar este foro como ultimo recurso, estoy probando distintos for anidados, bucles, de todo tipo, pero nada bien hecho y ningun resultado. No quiero pasar algo mal hecho o sin sentido

Comment: pasalo igual, siempre, asi podemos ayudarte a corregir tu logica tambien...

Comment: X es un string? Los números los tienes declarados como int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los caracteres en C, en realidad son transformados a código ASCII.

Como verás, los códigos ASCII **son simplemente enteros**. Puedes encontrar el listado completo [aquí](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int c = 'x';
```

El ejemplo de arriba es equivalente a:

```c
int c = 120; //El "120" es el código ASCII del caracter "x".
```

Entonces, este código imprime el caracter `x`:

```c
int x = 120;
printf("%c", x);
```

Sabiendo esto, podemos resolver tu problema fácilmente, lo único que debemos hacer es:

**1.-** Comparar cada elemento del *array* `bolas` con los elementos de la matriz `carton`.

**2.-** Sí llegamos a encontrar dicho elemento en la matriz, entonces le asignamos el código ASCII (del caracter `x`) en una determinada columna de `X` fila.

Como dicen por ahí, sí divides el problema, vencerás el problema. Por lo tanto, podemos crear una función que se encargue de sustituir la `x`:

```c
void sustituir(int carton[][5], int bolas[], int len_bolas)
{
    //Recorremos el array "bolas"..
    for(int i = 0; i != len_bolas; ++i)
        //Recorremos las filas de la matriz "carton"..
        for(int fil = 0; fil != 3; ++fil)
            //Recorremos las columnas de la matriz "carton"..
            for(int col = 0; col != 5; ++col)
                //Si la bola está en el carton..
                if(bolas[i] == carton[fil][col])
                    //Asignamos la x..
                    carton[fil][col] = 'x';
}
```

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```c
int main(void)
{
    int bolas[] = {1, 5, 4, 9, 5};
    int carton[3][5] = 
    {
        {1, 0, 4, 43, 21},
        {41, 53, 46, 86, 66},
        {84, 41, 7, 8, 9}
    };
    sustituir(carton, bolas, sizeof bolas / sizeof bolas[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
            printf((carton[i][j] == 'x') ? "%c\t" : "%d\t", carton[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado en pantalla sería:

```c
x   0   x   43   21
41  53  46  86   66
84  41  7   8    x
```

Comment: Tengo una pregunta dave, Cual es el sentido de guardar como parametro las variables con sizeof?

Comment: Estoy imprimiendo las variables como bolas utilizando sizeof, esta me da 60, ¿Con que sentido lo utilizas? Me interesa entender este sizeof ya que lo veo mucho en posts de C en stackoverflow

Comment: @HatoriHanso En el ejemplo use `sizeof` para obtener la longitud del array directamente, sin la necesidad de contar los elementos manualmente y asi evitas escribir tu mismo la longitud del array (esa es la finalidad). En tu caso, el array bolas y carton, los datos no son inicializados manualmente, sino, son datos aleatorios obtenidos en tiempo de ejecucion, entonces ahi, no hace falta que uses el `sizeof`. Asi que tranquilamente puedes eliminar el ultimo parametro que le puse a la funcion `sustituir`.

Comment: En tu caso, lo que deberias definir es la capacidad del array por medio de una macro, ej: `#define NUM_BOLAS  90` .

Comment: Muchas gracias como siempre @MrDave199

Answer (score -1):

```
int row = sizeof(carton) / sizeof(carton[0]);
int column = sizeof(carton[0])/row;
for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<column;j++)
         for(int z=0; z<sizeof(bolas)/sizeof(bolas[0]);z++)
           if(bolas[z] == carton[i][j])
               carton[i][j] = "X";
```

Recorres la matriz de cartón , y haces un if comparando si es igual el elemento de la matriz con el elemento iesimo de bolas , si es igual se sustituye en la matriz con una X

Comment: for i es el size of bolas

Comment: Viendo la asignación de `carton [3][5] = {1, 0, 4, 43, 21,41, 53, 46, 86, 66, 84, 41, 7, 8, 9,}`, qué pasará cuando le asignes un `"X"`? Porque supongo que los tiene declarados como arrays de enteros

Comment: i sigue yendo mal... no va a llegar nunca al final del array de bolas... falta un for aca

Comment: No sé qué pasará , el simplemente dice que sustituyas con una X , así que imagino que los números son de tipo de char , y no de int. Porque si fuera int la X se tendría que sustituir como null en vez de cómo "X"

Comment: *así que imagino que los números son de tipo de char* **-->** viendo la asignación, son claramente `int`, y al asignarles una "X" les estás asignando la dirección de memoria de una variable no declarada (el string X), con lo cual cuando intente leerlo le dará un valor totalmente aleatorio leído de vete a saber qué dirección de memoria.

Comment: He añadido otro for , ahora debería de recorrer el array de bolas entero cada vez que se compare fila,columna de carton.

Comment: Y con respecto a X , hasta que no nos dé más información no sabremos más

Comment: @RoyalUp con la X lo que hace es que cuando un numero salido en la bola este en la matriz carton, este se remplace por una X como si fuera una **marca**

Comment: Esto esta mal: `sizeof(carton[0])/row;`, esto no obtiene la longitud de la columna. Deberia ser asi: `sizeof(carton[0])/sizeof(carton[0][0])`.